# What should I answer if someone asks 'What is/was 'someone''?

Tags: questions

> A. Fabricius was Harvey's tutor.
>  
>   B. Fabricius was the first to discover the valves of the veins.

If someone asks that what was Fabricius?; which answer can I give? A or B?

Who was Fabricius ?
Which is more correct A or B.

Answer (score 1):

When we ask about *someone's **profession**, we use 'what'.

Say--

> ***What is*** your father? ~ He's ***a tutor***

So, here, if someone is asking 'what is Fabricius', the answer should be Fabricius' profession.

> ***What is*** Fabricius? ~ He was ***Harvey's tutor.***

---

'What is *someone?*' to ask ***profession*** seems to be InE *(Thanks NateEldredge)*.

Comment: I don't think this is idiomatic in contemporary American English.  If somebody asked me "What is your father?", I'd be confused for a few moments and probably answer "Um... a human."  I wouldn't interpret it as a question about his profession.  The usual phrasing in AmE would be "What does your father do?"

Comment: @NateEldredge strange! I have *grown up* listening to 'what is your father' replied by 'A doctor' in India. I trust you and now have to 'delearn' it.

Comment: It's completely fine in AmE to say "My father is a doctor" (and this would be a typical response to "What does your father do?").  So it would be logical to ask "What is your father?" - but that simply isn't usual in AmE.